# Get Filenames From Folder in Gridview Control in ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need shows the file names from a folder into a GridView control.

I thinked use the **Directory class**.

In my database I have the column **sFolder** with this value for each row:

```
control/Imp/foo
```

I have tried this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f50501/get-filenames-from-folder-in-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net/) on the web but I can't get the file names from a folder into a GridView control.

I don't have error but the GridView is empty even if the path to the folder is correct.

My code below.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated

**.cs**

```
dt2 = new DataTable();
ds2 = new DataSet();

sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM tbl_2 WHERE sFolder IN ('control/Imp/foo'); ");

using (OdbcConnection cn =
  new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OdbcCommand cmd =
        new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
    {

        OdbcDataAdapter adapter =
            new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds2);

        if (ds2.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            dt2 = ds2.Tables[0];
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("/myFolder/" + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sFolder"].ToString().Replace('/', '\\'));
            Response.Write(FilePath);

// the response write FilePath is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet\myFolder\control\Imp\foo // 

            string[] filesLoc = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath);
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string file in filesLoc)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file)));
            }
            gvDownload.DataSource = files;
            gvDownload.DataBind();

        }
    }
}

return ds2;
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDownload" EmptyDataText="Data empty"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="FileName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**#Edit 01**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }


    private void BindData()
    {
        RetrieveProductsDowload();
    }

    private DataSet RetrieveProductsDowload()
    {
dt2 = new DataTable();
ds2 = new DataSet();

sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM tbl_2 WHERE sFolder IN ('control/Imp/foo'); ");

using (OdbcConnection cn =
  new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OdbcCommand cmd =
        new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
    {

        OdbcDataAdapter adapter =
            new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds2);

        if (ds2.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            dt2 = ds2.Tables[0];
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("/myFolder/" + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sFolder"].ToString().Replace('/', '\\'));
            Response.Write(FilePath);

// the response write FilePath is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet\myFolder\control\Imp\foo // 

            string[] filesLoc = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath);
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string file in filesLoc)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file)));
            }
            gvDownload.DataSource = files;
            gvDownload.DataBind();

        }
    }
}

return ds2;

}
```

Comment: Try: `gvDownload.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath); gvDownload.DataBind();`, use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, and remove `<Columns>...</Columns>` from GridView. Does it work?

Comment: @Ritesh thank you for reply, but don't work, the GV is empty.

Comment: Did you use `Page_Load` in .cs file to write this code?

Comment: @Ritesh Please see #Edit01 in my first question.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this:

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
gvDownload.DataSource = allfiles;
gvDownload.DataBind();
```